# How do I call HTMLDocument.prototype.write?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a scriptlet that calls document.write("something"). On some pages it fails because document.write has been redefined. According to this page I can however find the old definition of the function:

Fixing the JavaScript typeof operator | JavaScript, JavaScript... http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/

So it is in HTMLDocument.prototype.write - but how do I call it??

Comment: Why `document.write` was redefined?

Comment: You might want to re-think using document.write as it can be very destructive and heavy-handed. It's possible that the pages you've found that redefine it do so specifically to avoid scripts using it.

Comment: Not all browsers implement prototype inheritance, you can't use `HTMLDocument...` in those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
HTMLDocument.prototype.write.call(document, 'something');
```